# one linq query to load many to many relationship

Tags: linq-to-sql, many-to-many

There are so many similar questions, and I did my research before I post this question.

I have3 tables, its many to many relationship.

Post: PostID, PostName

Tag: TagId, TagName

PostTag: PostTagID, PostID, TagID

here's my code in the controller.

```
    public ActionResult List(int page = 1, int record = 10)
    {
        return View((IEnumerable<Post>)GetPosts(page, record));
    }

    public IList<Post> GetPosts(int page = 1, int record = 10)
    {
        var options = new DataLoadOptions();

        options.LoadWith<Post>(p => p.PostTags);
        options.LoadWith<PostTag>(pt => pt.Tag);

        using (var db = new mvc3codesDataContext())
        {
            db.LoadOptions = options;

            return (from p in db.Posts select p).ToList();
        }


    }
```

this is the code in my view file.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostName)
        <br />

        @foreach (var pt in item.PostTags)  -----> this part not working. 
        {                                 

        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

It shows a list of posts, but I dont know how to output the tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, pt is a PostTag, not the Tag itself. In this case, you need to think of the Many-Many relationship more as a 1-0..*-1. In this case, you would be accessing the pt.Tag.Property.

Comment: I try to do "item.Tags", but intellisense didnt have "Tags" in the list.